# Odd NoMethodError on validation fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a strange NoMethodError that's appearing when a form fails validation in Rails. I can access the 'new' method without a problem to fill out the form the first time. But then the form submits to a nested controller and if validation fails, it tried to redirect to 'new' again (as it should) but throws `undefined method articles_path`.

I thought it might be to do with the nesting, but I believe the setup here is correct for it to load the nested 'new' path?

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious... But why is this happening?

Controller:

```
  def new
    @user = User.find(current_user)
    @article = Article.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @article }
    end
  end

  def create
    @article = current_user.articles.build(params[:article])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, :flash => { :notice => 
          "Article added!" } }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @article.errors, :status => 
          :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Form:

```
= form_for([@user, @article], :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
  - if @article.errors.any?
    #errorExplanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error")
        prohibited this post from being saved:
      %ul
        - @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .clearfix
    = f.label :title, "Article title *"
    .input
      = f.text_field :title
```

Comment: Try setting @user in your create method as your new form needs it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that the error is caused by nested resource, particularly this part of the code

```
= form_for([@user, @article], :html => ...
```

When validation fails, `@user` is nil which causes the url to look like `[nil, @article]` which turns into articles_path if `@article` is not persisted. So the solution is to set `@user` in the create action.

Comment: @Nick, just a not about setting `@user`. Instead of `@user = User.find(current_user)` you can simply do `@user = current_user`.

Comment: Oh - good to know, thanks. Is that purely for code readability or is there an associated database query improvement?

Comment: `current_user` is already the user object that you want/need so you don't need to fetch it from the database.